# Updating multiple table record data via ajax in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have an ajax request as shown below

```
var user = $('#user_id').attr("data-user"); 
var data =  {"message_attributes":
    [{credits: 150}]
};
$.ajax({
    url: "/messages/" + user, 
    type: "PUT",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'html',
    complete: function() {},
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        alert("Updated!");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Could not process your request!");
    }
})
```

The messages/:user_id routes to a custom update action

```
def custom_update
  if Message.where('user_id = ?',params[:user_id]).update_all(params[:message_attributes])  
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :json => true }
    end 
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {  render :json => false }
    end
  end
end
```

Note: credits is an attribute of the Message model (i.e. there is credits column in the messages table)

I want the custom_update action to be dynamic such that it'll update the columns  based on what the messages_attributes contains. Sometimes it'll have credits, other times it'll have other attributes of the Message model that i want to send via ajax. The Message.where().update_all(params[:message_attributes]) should be able to identify them and update them accordingly.
How do i do this?

With the above code I'm getting this error
"NoMethodError undefined method '%' for {credits: 150}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case the problem is that you are trying to use JSON in your `update_all`. For it to work you should do`JSON.parse(params[:message_attributes])` which would decode your JSON array into ruby hash.
Also, I think that the `[]` around params is not needed in this case, since all your params are going to be in the same curly brackets (`{}`) either way.

you can also change your updating line to `Message.where(user_id: params[:user_id]).update_all(params[:message_attributes])` to prevent SQL injections.

WARNING: DO NOT use raw params like this. They are vulnerable to attacks, because anyone can change them to any attribute and update all `Message` records.

Instead use whitelisting

```
def message_params
  params.require(:message_attributes).permit(:credits, :param2, :param3)
end
```

And then

```
Message.where(user_id: params[:user_id]).update_all(message_params)
```

This way nobody will be able to inject other params in the update, since the `message_params` will drop all params that are not whitelisted.

SUGGESTION: Use tools like `byebug` or `binding.pry` to track your errors. That's a very handy tool and should be used without mercy.

Comment: it works! Thank you. I normally whitelist params but thought because i was using ajax no one would see the URL, naive of me

Comment: One problem I'm noticing is that it's not actually storing the number, the ajax call succeeds but the value of credits in the db table is 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Check if the value is passed to the controller. Could you paste the post request log?

Comment: caught my mistake...I was doing Message.where(id: params[:user_id]).update_all instead of Message.where(user_id: params[:user_id]).update_all